# Issues retrieving and incrementing Parse object

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

I am trying to retrieve a PFObject, add 1 to the vote count and re-save to Parse.

I am using Swift to successfully retrieve a PFObject, but am having trouble when I try to increment a nested value using the incrementKey() function.

**I first tried:**

```
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Quests")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(questId) {
        (retrievedQuest: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        } else {
            if let theQuest = retrievedQuest {
                if let options = theQuest["options"]{
                    println(options[row])
                    options[row].incrementKey("votes", byAmount: 1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I receive the following error:

```
-[__NSDictionaryM incrementKey:byAmount:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8acaf97dd0
```

**I next tried:**

```
var options = theQuest["options"] as! [PFObject]
```

and got: fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

**Next, I tried breaking down the elements within my PFObject to try to increment 'votes' manually**

```
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Quests")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(questId) {
        (retrievedQuest: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        } else {
            if let theQuest = retrievedQuest {
                var options = theQuest["options"] as! NSArray
                var theOption = options[row] as! NSDictionary
                var theVotes = theOption["votes"] as! Int
                theVotes++
                retrievedQuest?.saveInBackground()
```

It's probably pretty obvious that incrementing theVotes this way doesn't affect retrievedQuest, saving retrievedQuest doesn't reflect any update to votes.

Any ideas on how I can get my desired outcome?

Comment: What is options?  An array of PFObjects?  If so then use a typecast to tell Swift this, but your exception says that options actually constains a mutableDictionary, which doesn't implement incrementKey:byAmount

Comment: NSDictionary does not have an `incrementKey` method.

Comment: I added a bunch of additional information to my original question.  Thanks for the guidance so far.

Answer (score 0):

Swift doesn't know the type of `options`. As Paulw11 says, you need to cast to the correct type. If options is an array of `PFObject`s (as your code implies), then changing

```
if let options = theQuest["options"]{ 
  println(options[row])
  options[row].incrementKey("votes", byAmount: 1)
}
```

to

```
if let options = theQuest["options"] as? [PFObject] { 
  println(options[row])
  options[row].incrementKey("votes", byAmount: 1)
}
```

may fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks rickerbh - I tried to do that, but using as! resulted in the error 'fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type'.  Using as? resulted in options evaluating to nil.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI - I solved this by eliminating the options array and, instead, having each option be a unique property of the class.  Can now just use

```
theQuest.incrementKey("option\(row)")
```